# Does django (python) reuse object?

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a model with a field `field1`

```
class MyClass(models.Model):

   field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Somewhere I have a code like

```
my_object = MyClass()

my_object.field1 = 'a'
my_object.another_field = 'b' # (it's not defined in the model class)
```

Is there a chance that `another_object = MyClass()` could have `another_field set`?

Comment: No, you don't `another_field` only accessible on your `my_object` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `another_field` will be unique to the instance that you assigned it to. This is particular to python, irrespective of Django. Try this in the python console:

```
>>> class MyClass():
>>>   field1 = "field 1"
>>> x = MyClass()
>>> x.another_field = "another field!"
>>> x.field1
'field 1'
>>> x.another_field
'another field!'
>>> y = MyClass()
>>> y.field1
'field 1'
>>> y.another_field
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: MyClass instance has no attribute 'another_field'
```

If you want to add a new field to the class dynamically, you can do so by adding it directly to the class (as opposed to an instance) as follows:

```
>>> MyClass.newer_field = "this is the newest field"
```

Now, you can see that the newer field is available, even to existing objects:

```
>>> x.newer_field
'this is the newest field'
>>> y.newer_field
'this is the newest field'
```